# using contenteditable with wysiwyg in meteor

Tags: meteor, wysiwyg, redactor.js

I'm trying to use redactor.js to edit in place some divs in meteor;
in the template I have:

```
<template name="home">
    <section class="editable">
    </section>
    ...
</template>
```

and in the js:

```
Template.home.events({
    "click section.editable": function(event) {
        $(event.target).redactor();
    },
});
```

this creates the redactor wysiwyg editor correctly when I click on the section; the problem is that by clicking again, another editor (nested inside the previous one is created); I'm trying without success to limit the execution of redactor() method only if the editor is not there already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you wrap the state in a session variable? Of course, you'd need to set it back again once the redactor was finished (maybe try hooking into a blur event?)

```js
Template.home.events({
    "click section.editable": function(event) {
        var isEditorActive = Session.get("editorActive", false);
        if (!isEditorActive) {
            Session.set("editorActive",true);
            $(event.target).redactor({
                blurCallback: function(e)
                {
                    Session.set("editorActive",false);
                    this.core.destroy(); // destroy redactor ?
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

> ***PREVIOUSLY:***
>
> Is there a particular reason you want to use meteor events for this? You could just use redactor.
>
> ```js
> if (Meteor.isClient) {
>     Meteor.startup(function() {
>         $('section.editable').redactor({
>             focus: false
>         });
>     });
> }
> ```

Comment: Well the reason to bind it to the click event is that I'm Trying to implement a click-to-edit mode; I don't want to startup with the editor  already there; just a normal div, and when you click on it, the editor shows itself

Comment: @CerealKiller I've updated my answer. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Yes but this solution doesn't support more editors active at same time (you will need something more complex than a variable to track editor states...); finally I used a solution that add a custom (editing) class when the editor is activated and remove it when is deactivated; checking if the editor .hasClass('.editing') let you decide if you have to call redactor() method or not...

Comment: Ah, I see. That requirement wasn't clear from the question. Thanks for accepting the answer.